# lcm$(p(x),q(x)) \cdot \gcd(p(x),q(x)) \sim p(x)q(x)$ holds for $D[x]$ with D u.f.d?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $D$ be an u.f.d and $p(x),q(x) \in D[x]$ is it necessary that:

lcm$(p(x),q(x))\cdot\gcd(p(x),q(x)) = up(x)q(x)$?
Where $u \in D$ is invertible.

I know this fact is true if $D[x]=F[x]$ where $F$ is a field and the proof of that required p.i.d so my bet is that this doesnt hold for any d.f.u however I can't come up with a counter-example.

Comment: If $D$ is a UFD, then so is $D[x]$. Also, the statement about LCMs and GCDs is true in any UFD, not just PIDs.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang How could I prove it without using the fact that if $p(x),q(x) \in D[x]$ where $D[x]$ is u.f.d then there exists $a(x),b(x) \in D[x]$ s.t $\gcd(p(x),q(x)) = a(x)p(x) + b(x)q(x)$

Comment: write p(x) and q(x) in terms of irreducibles. Can you write lcm and gcd in terms of those?